# Is the usage of message.author correct

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to add an event to my bot where it responds whenever a specific profile says something in the channel, my idea was to compare
`message.author`
to a string and then it will send a message

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('bot is ready')
    print(client.user)
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(f"'{message.content}' said by {message.author}")
    if message.author == "MESSAGE AUTHOR":
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author} said something")
```

again when 
`message.author` 
matches up with the string, currently "MESSAGE AUTHOR", a response should be made by the bot, but this is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

A `User` object like `message.author` will never be equal to a string.  You could test the string representation of the user, which is composed of their username and discriminator:

```
if str(message.author) == "Junar#1234":
```

A better idea would be to use their id.  Users can change their usernames, and thus their string representations, but they cannot change their ids.

```
if message.author.id == 1234567890:
```

You can either write some discord code to output a user's id, or you can enable developer mode in the discord client and right click on their name in the list of members.