# Specific command executed by certain user - discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am using discord.py in Replit to make my Discord Bot. I want to make a command that is executed when two statements are true. First is that it is the correct command, and second is that the person who typed it is me, the maker. How do I make this code?

Here is a link to the code - https://replit.com/@DerekWeber/DiscordBot#main.py

Please help me...

Comment: You're looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65844706/how-does-is-owner-works)

Comment: I edited the question adding a link to the code.

Comment: Instead of adding a link to your code, add the part of the code that you are having trouble with, thanks.

Comment: I want to add a command that runs when a specific user types the command. I don't know how to implement that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `message.author.id` to get the user's Discord ID like:

```py
#Import discord and other modules.

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == yourdiscordid:
        print("It's me!")
        
    else:
        print("It's you, not me!")

#Run the bot.
```

Replace `yourdiscordid` with your Discord ID (not your bot's), and the `message` parameter of the `on_message()` function is the *first* parameter of the function.

How to get your Discord ID: right-click on your profile (in Discord) and then click "Copy ID" from the menu.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56060510/16136190) to understand how to use `message.author.id`.